# WPF Displaying Parent Child relationship

Tags: wpf, parent-child

I can't wrap my head around how to accomplish rendering this

```
public class Shape{}
public class Circle: Shape{}
public class Square: Shape
{
    public List<Circle> CircleList{ get; private set; }
}
```

I have a List that holds Shape objects, now what I want to accomplish is having each object rendered in a grid.

If the object is a Square there should be a nested grid that holds Circle items from the CircleList property

I've tried with an ItemsControl and a HierarchicalDataTemplate, could not get it working, i've tried nesting an ItemsControl inside an ItemsControl, i'm pretty new to WPF so i'm kinda fumbling around here not knowing what the "proper" solution would be. I did manage to render the above in a TreeView, but what i'm trying to accomplish is a drawingboard that renders shapes.

**UPDATE**

The "Drawingboard" should contain items, each item should  be rendered in a container.

If the object is of Type Square the Square container should have a nested container to hold the Circle objects from the CircleList Property.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just a little confused by a typo.  It's obvious that Square derives from Shape, but you have {} brackets after that... should they not be there?

Comment: Just empty brackets for the class where the constructor and such should be

Comment: But aren't the 3 lines after that the definition of the class?

Comment: Fixed the typo, and added some clarification on the "drawingboard"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott is pretty close but not *quite* there; setting the DataContext of the Grid will not render the contained Circle objects. What you need is an embedded control that can render its own items, and then bind the ItemsSource property of that control to the CircleList.

I have constructed an example using your original classes that demonstrates this. Here is the code-behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Square square = new Square();
        square.CircleList = new List<Circle>() { new Circle(25) };
        _shapes.Add(square);
    }

    private List<Shape> _shapes = new List<Shape>();

    public List<Shape> Shapes
    {
        get { return _shapes; }
    }
}

public abstract class Shape { }

public class Circle : Shape
{
    public double Diameter { get; private set; }

    public Circle(double diameter)
    {
        Diameter = diameter;
    }
}

public class Square : Shape
{
    public List<Circle> CircleList { get; set; }
}
```

So you can see I have added a single Square to my Shapes list, that contains a circle of diameter 25. Note that this does not add any support for positioning the shapes using absolute coordinates; I assume you already have something in place for that.

Now the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApplication"
Title="Window1"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Circle}">
        <Ellipse Stroke="Black" 
                 Width="{Binding Diameter}" 
                 Height="{Binding Diameter}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Square}">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CircleList}"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Here are your DataTemplates; you can see the Circle is rendered simply with an Ellipse. The Square, on the other hand, has an embedded ItemsControl that renders its contained items. I have also drawn a Border around it to make the square shape.

Here is the result:

[alt text http://img212.imageshack.us/img212/8658/squarewithcirclecontent.png](http://img212.imageshack.us/img212/8658/squarewithcirclecontent.png)

Comment: +1 - I was a little confused by the original question saying he was displaying them in a grid, and I figured he had some other data template for rendering a "grid" from a list.  You've solved that with an ItemsControl.

Comment: nice, atleast I got it to render now :D now I got something to work with :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using two DataTemplates, one for a Circle (just renders a Circle) and one for a Square.  The Square DataTemplate should render a Grid (just give it a border to make it look like a square) and then set the nested Grid's DataContext="{Binding CircleList}".

I'm not 100% sure how you're converting a list of shapes to a grid, but sounds like you've already got that solved, so I'll just omit that for simplicity.  :)

Comment: i'm kinda confused as to what I would be defining the specific datatemplates in, basicly if I knew how to make it, i'd use an ItemsControl, I want to have a "drawingboard" this drawingboard holds a list of items, theese items should be rendered in a certain manner.

Comment: @thmsn - The "drawingboard" you're describing is a bit odd, from a functionality standpoint. It won't allow items to overlap with each other.  Why not just use a Canvas object, throw all your shapes in there, and let it render them.  Then you don't have to worry about what's "inside" of what.

Comment: the reason I want it to be nested is because the child objects position needs to be relative to the parents position :) they should allow to overlap though, so a canvas would propably be the right thing, they still need a nsted canvas though :)

Comment: @thmsn - consider structuring the tree backwards.  Add a Parent property to Shape (of type Shape).  Have just one list of all shapes, and add them all to your Canvas.  Have each shape dynamically calculate its own properties off of its parent's properties.  Have each shape subscribe to the property changed event of its parent too, so they recalculate on the fly, and raise their own property changed events.